# Good design of a localized YearWeek according to JSR-310

Tags: java, java-time, date, jsr310

I need an object that represents a localized concept of a seven days week. That object is pretty much the same as the [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library, except that the first day and the minimal number of days varies.

I thought initially to implement a `LocalizedYearWeek`, with some factory methods such as `LocalizedYearWeek.of(int year, int week, WeekDefinition weekDefinition)`. The class `WeekDefinition` is merely a value object that defines the first day and the minimal number of days of a week, that can also work as a factory of `WeekFields`.

I'm not sure if it is the best model for such temporal, but I didn't come up with any better design ideas, so I'm looking for some guidance on how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
WeekFields.of( 
    firstDayOfWeek , 
    minimumDaysInFirstWeek 
)
```

## `WeekFields`

The *java.time* classes already support non-standard weeks. You may not need to build your own class. An implementation of [`java.time.Temporal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html) with the necessary [`TemporalField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html) objects has been provided in the [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) class.

The [`WeekFields.ISO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#ISO) constant uses standard [ISO 8601 definition of a week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date):

- Week # 1 holds the first Thursday of the calendar-year.
- Week # 1 has 4 or more of its days in January
- Week begins on Monday, ends on Sunday.

But that class is built for alternative week definitions as well. The constant `WeekFields.SUNDAY_START` comes configured for United States-style Sunday-Monday weeks.

```
DayOfWeek dow = WeekFields.SUNDAY_START.getFirstDayOfWeek() ;
```

> dow.toString(): SUNDAY

Get the week number and week-based-year number:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
int w = ld.get( WeekFields.SUNDAY_START.weekOfWeekBasedYear() ) ;
int y = ld.get( WeekFields.SUNDAY_START.weekBasedYear() ) ;
```

If you define a week differently, configure `WeekFields` as needed.

```
DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ;
int minimumDaysInFirstWeek = 4 ;
WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of( firstDayOfWeek , minimumDaysInFirstWeek ) ;
int w = ld.get( wf.weekOfWeekBasedYear() ) ;
int y = ld.get( wf.weekBasedYear() ) ;
```

If you want to represent a year-week as a single unit, then yes, you will need to write your own class similar to [`org.threeten.extra.YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class from [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/). Such a class would contain the `WeekFields` object shown above, and would offer methods wrapping the code seen above. The source-code for [`YearWeek.java`](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.java) is available with a liberal license.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. I'm familiar with the JRS310 specification and capabilities. However, as mentioned, the whole point around this thread is to discuss the best way to represent a localized year-week as a single unit. Is indeed a good idea to wrap the `WeekFields`? I'm interested not only in the week number but also in the operations involving it, such as getting a day of that week, creating an interval from it, etc.

Comment: @MarcosPassos Then your Question is too broad for Stack Overflow. This page is not a thread, and this site is not for discussions. Try another site such as http://www.JavaRanch.com/.

Comment: Personally I see nothing wrong with a homegrown class encompassing a year, a week number and a reference to the appropriate `WeekFields` object. I would expect many instances of your class to share the same `WeekFields` object, so it’s not so wasteful as one might first imagine. @MarcosPassos